# Getting a script to run using file length on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

I need a script to run whenever a file is to long (rename the file.  Say a rcv file is put into a folder and it is named 123456789.rcv.  But the program we use to grab this will not take it because the name is to long.  So I made a script to rename the file by deleting 2 numbers.  But I only need the script to run when it is over 7 digits long.  How is the IF statement written for this if there is one?  here is what I have so far.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*.rcv) do (
set oldname=%%a

rem     GRABS FIRST 5 Characters of file name
set first=!oldName:~0,5!

rem     GRABS all but first 7 characters of file name
set newName=!oldName:~7!

rem     ADDS two stings together to create new file name
Set newName2=!first!!newName!

rem     RENAMES old file name to new file name
Ren "!oldName!" "!newName2!"

timeout /t 10
quite
)
```

Comment: Hmm. Your current script doesn't come close to keeping file names under 7 characters ;) - 5 + n-7 != 7

Comment: What do you want to do if the filenames clash? For example: `123456789.rcv` and `1234567ab.rcv`. You can't rename both of them to `1234567.rcv`

Comment: [How do you get the string length in a batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837418/how-do-you-get-the-string-length-in-a-batch-file)

Comment: The first 5 digits of the file are the costumers number, the remaining digits are random except the last 2.  Our program that process the orders will only take the file if its at or under 7 digits.  So we have been going in and renaming each file (order) by deleting 2 digits from the middle.  This will do that for us, we just don't want to do it to the files that are already 7 digits long or under.  Only the 8 and 9 digit files.  Won't have to worry about files being the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
if not "!oldName:~7!"=="" ()
```

will be `true` if `oldName` is more than 7 characters long.

Of course, this tests the whole `123456789.rcv` filename. Since you actually seem to refer to the filename part without extension only, you can test `%%~na`, which will be `123456789` in this example.

```
SET FN=%%~na
if not "!FN:~7!"=="" ()
```

(or just test for a length of 11)